# Basic probability…balls extraction

Tags: probability

im stuck with a basic probability problem:

n balls --> n-1 extraction. Only one black ball. No replacement.

example:

7 balls(6 white, 1 black). 6 extractions.

i know that the probablity of 6 whites is: 6/7 · 5/6 · 4/5 · 3/4 · 2/3 · 1/2 = 0.14 aprox, so the prob of get the black ball is: 1 - 0.14 = 0.86

but how can i calculate the probabilities of black in six extraction without using the above technique?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Another thinking of your answer would be $1-{1\over{7\choose 6}}$ but is essentially the same thing as the above technique.

Other than that you would use ${6\choose 5}\over{7\choose 6}$ by fixing the black ball to be chosen and choose $5$ from the remaining $6$ balls.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're meant to realise that the probability of drawing $n-1$ balls is the same as the probability of *leaving* $1$ ball in the bag at the end. Therefore probability of six white draws $= \frac{1}{7}$ and probability of five white and one black is the same as leaving a white behind $=\frac{6}{7}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Extracting $n-1$ balls from $n$ balls without replacement (1) comes to the same as extracting $1$ ball from $n$ balls without replacement (2). Just think of this extracted ball in (2) as the unique ball wich is *not* extracted in (1).

Answer (score 0):

The probability of drawing a black ball is the complement of not drawing a black ball:

$$P (\mbox {drawing black})=1-P (\mbox {not drawing black})$$

Not drawing the single black ball when drawing $n-1$ balls from $n$ balls is simply $\frac {1}{n} $, so the probability you're after is:

$$1-\frac {1}{n}=\frac {n-1}{n}$$

Comment: Thanks all..i know your answer is right but i really dont understand it:

Comment: ...continue...How logically you get that 1/n is the prob. of not extract back? my mind says that extract black must be something like 1/7+1/6+1/5+1/4+1/3+1/2, that obviously is not...but why??

Comment: When extracting $n-1$ from $n$ balls, you are basically seperating the $n$ balls into two groups; of size 1 and size $n-1$. The probability that the black ball is not in the group of size $n-1$, is the probability that the black ball is in the group of size 1. Now, the probability of selecting the black ball from the $n $ balls is $\frac {1}{n} $.

Comment: logically got it...thanx.....but why mathematicaly i can't express the probs. of black as six "sums(or mult.) of probs" (one for each extraction) as i do with the whites?

Comment: You can, it comes down to the same thing: $\frac {6}{7}\frac {5}{6}\frac {4}{5}\frac {3}{4}\frac {2}{3}\frac {1}{2}=\frac {6!}{7!}=\frac {1}{7}$

Comment: but that defines the "white" extract not the black...

Comment: That is what you asked for, right? If not, I am inclear what you ask for. What I meant with my answer is that looking at it as "6 white balls" or "1 black ball" are different approaches, but yield the same result. :)

Comment: Excuse me Eric for my brais mess... i tried to do: 1/7·1/6·1/5·1/4·1/3/·1/2, because i thought this express the probs of black in the same way i do with whites, but i dont know why i can't express this way

Comment: Sorry, I honestly don't know if you're still unclear and are asking another question, or if you understand it now and are explaining what you didn't understand before...

Answer (score 0):

If you have $n$ balls, you can, in the beginning, fix the black ball (i.e. it'll be present in all of your combinations). Then, you can choose $n-2$ balls from the remaining $n-1$ balls. You can do it in ${n-1\choose n-2}=n-1$. If you were to choose any $n-1$ balls from $n$ balls, you could do it in ${n \choose n-1}=n$ ways. So, the probability of getting the black ball in your combination is $\frac{n-1}{n}$.

Answer (score 0):

1. You want to draw 6 balls and the remaining ball should be black.
2. Exactly one of your seven balls is black. So the six balls you draw in 1. are  white and the remaining ball is black
3. If you draw 7 balls (all balls) then 2. is the same as if you draw 6 white balls and at last a black ball. So the balls are drawn in the following order: *w w w w w w b*
4. The sequence does not matter. 3. has the same probability as drawing a black ball with the first draw and drawing white balls in the remaining 6 draws. Here the balls are drawn in the following order: *b w w w w w w*
   5.Because there is only one black balls. is the same as drawing one ball, which is black. The remaining balls are all white.
5. The probability of drawing a black ball is $\frac{1}{7}$